# Can we create a SQL Server RDS in AWS Active/Active?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, multi-master-replication

I have question about AWS RDS. what we have to do to create a SQL Server RDS Active/Active or Multi-Master Cluster on AWS? Is there any easy way in AWS RDS? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your requirement absolutely *must* have the ability to commit transactions to multiple database server instances, what you need is [Always On Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server) (AGs).  To set this up in Amazon RDS SQL Server, here's the [relevant bit of the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_SQLServerMultiAZ.html).  That should be enough to get you started!

Comment: thanks for answer. I will try...